# How to control the speed of a Mantaflow fluid simulation in 2.93?

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation, mantaflow

Time scale seems to work, but I'm unsure if that's the correct way to do it.

In older versions of blender there was a "Speed" value. This is gone now.

[image]

The reason I'm asking is because I'm following a tutorial and my simulation runs way slower than the tutorials despite having the same settings.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you should be able to change the speed simulation with the *Settings > Time Scale* value:

[image]